# Remove last empty line from select field with "for" loop wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, select

I am create a custom widget in WordPress and in the widget I try to create a select field with for loop and shows in it 10 numbers from 1 to 10.

I created BUT underneath number 10 it have an empty line.

Can you help me to remove that empty line?

[image: this is number 10] [image: this is an empty line under number 10]

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">
<select width="50" style="width: 50px"  class='widefat' id=" <?php $this->get_field_id('timet8t2'); ?>" name="<?php $this->get_field_name('timet8t2'); ?>" type="text">

<?php 
    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
    {

        echo "<option value=".$i.">"."$i<br>"."</option>";
    }
?> 


    <option name="<?php $this->get_field_name('timet8t2'); ?>"> </option> 
  </select> 
</label>
```

Comment: There is no label for the option generated from `$this->get_field_name('timet8t2')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

You need to remove the last option:

```
<option name="<?php $this->get_field_name('timet8t2'); ?>"><?= $this->get_field_name('timet8t2'); ?></option>
```

### Part 2

To display the option label with a leading 0, you can use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

See Below:

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('timet8t2'); ?>">
    <select width="50" style="width: 50px"  class='widefat' id=" <?php $this->get_field_id('timet8t2'); ?>" name="<?php $this->get_field_name('timet8t2'); ?>" type="text">

<?php 
    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$i.">". sprintf("%'.02d", $i) . "</option>";
    }
?> 
  </select> 
</label>
```

[Simplified PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5799c8b186e6b333afb86dca2e6fb509121c4a0e)

Comment: Hello segFault, it works. The empty line underneath number 10, it completely removed!

 Please can you tell me how to change the numbers 1, 2, 3,... to 01, 02, 03... ? Thanks! :)

Comment: Have a look at [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), specifically: `echo sprintf("%'.02d\n", $i);` Can also use `printf()`

Comment: OK, my apologies..  In select field i want to shows numbers from 1 to 24 and and it displaying the numbers like "  01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24  "

Comment: yea, regardless of the number of options, you could use either of those functions... I can update my answer to do it for you np

Comment: It works!!!! segFault, i don't know how i say thanks. You are amazing!!! I hope that one day i can pay back the help! 
It is displaying the numbers like " 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, ... 
but at site (front-end) it shows " 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, ... " .

I think that is OK for now, so many thanks again!

Comment: Typically you say thanks by accepting the answer to your question and upvoting ;)